# Same Values unable to be inserted in SAP table

Tags: key, sap-data-dictionary

I have made two keys in the table in SAP, `mandt` and `subject` values of subject have to be repetitive. But I'm unable to insert same values. Error being shown is:

> an entry already exists with the same key

This error persists even after I remove subject as the key. This may be a silly question, but I'm new to world of SAP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that those values are keys is the issue. You must use any other field that make them non-unique.

I don't know your case but you can use another field, a sequence or a guid value.

Hope it helps.